# “one of the hyper-v components is not running” how to get more information on this issue?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, hyper-v-manager, windows-10-v21h1

I just reinstalled all Hyper‑V features after disabling them for using another hypervisor that didn’t support pci‑e passthrough.
[image]
There aren’t more details besides the virtual machine id. It’s happening with all virtual machines, even with the simplest case like above.

I know there are a lot of questions like this one which tells the issue has it’s root with nested virtualization, but in my case, **the host Windows is running directly on the real hardware**, and this is in the official `virtmgmt.msc` that the issue is happening as well as the `Start-VM` Powershell command.

How to get more details about the issue, like the said component which isn’t running ?

Comment: Basically an exact duplicate of https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/726846/with-windows-10-as-host-i-get-the-failed-to-start.html as it used to work.

Comment: When you launch `msinfo32`, does it show “A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.”? In `services.msc`, are any of the Hyper-V services _disabled_? (Most are “Manual (triggered)”)

Comment: @DanielBfor point *2*, everything is enabled and for point *1*, yes, it does say this, in which case do you mean Windows treats it's own Hyper-V hypervisor as a foreign one ? Because things like Virtualbox or Vmware works when Hyper‑V is disabled but vmmware caps ɴᴠᴍe size to 2Tib and Virtualbox doesn’t support trimming leaving only Hyper‑V with ᴘᴄɪe passthrough.

Comment: No, the message is fine. It means the hypervisor is running (not disabled using `bcdedit`).

Answer (score 0):

After a few months of running in circles I found a fix for my problem with exactly the same symptoms. Hopefully this helps you or others.

I had SVM enabled, everything seemed to check out and should have worked. Hyper V feature as well as Virtual Machine Platform all uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times. Continued to have the "one of the Hyper-V components is not running" as well as other issues with WSL.

I found an error in the Event Viewer application under `Applications and Service Logs->Microsoft->Windows->Hyper-V-VMMS->Admin`. This error indicated "The virtualization infrastructure driver (VID) is not running." I checked device manager and found that the `Microsoft Hyper-V Virtualization Infrastructure Driver` was disabled. Enabled and everything started working.

If you don't have that exact error you might find something else in the Hyper-V event logs. Mine was getting this specific error upon reboot, and different errors when attempting to boot a VM.

Full disclosure I believe I updated this to windows 11 as a pseudo bare-metal VM running on unraid with PCI-e passthrough which may have caused my issue.

Comment: Where is `Microsoft Hyper-V Virtualization Infrastructure Driver` inside `devmgmt.msc`?

Comment: Did you also had `A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.` ?

Comment: For finding it under devmgmt.msc I found it by choosing to view devices by connection instead of the default view by type. This can be found in the View dropdown on top. And yes I also saw Hyper-V will not be displayed both before and after the fix.